# SSD Partitioning upgraded MBA (Macbook Air Model A1370) SSD

Tags: hard-drive, partition, ssd, ms-office

I would like to 'ghost' a 128GB to a larger M.2 SSD.  Based on my experience with upgrading a Macbook to a larger SSD, MS-Office will shutdown.  The PC is a [MacBook Air "Core i5" 1.6 11" (Mid-2011)](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook-air/specs/macbook-air-core-i5-1.6-11-mid-2011-specs.html)

I would think (hope) that by partitioning the larger SSD to have the same size partition as the 128GB drive (MS-Office would 'see' the same drive?).  The goal is to ghost the 128GB drive to a partition on the new drive, such that MS-Office 2011 will not re-engage in the license exercise.  Has anyone had success using this strategy?  Ideally there would be a reference on the web.

Comment: Which version of Office? Admittedly I'm still on 2011, but I've not only cloned drives to the same machine but also moved them to other machines without triggering any licensing issues. [Hmm... maybe it should have done, as I now probably have the same copy running on 3 different machines by doing it that way - never thought about that license before... oops ;)

Comment: Yes 2011.   What programs / hardware did you use to migrate the OS / apps to the larger SSD?

Comment: Carbon Copy Cloner. I've used it for years to make safety copies, shift HD to SSD, dupe drives so I don't have to start from scratch on a new machine etc - never even thought about something springing up an 'oops' for licensing. [Oh, btw, I have 5 Office licenses, so my conscience is clear on having 3 of the same copy, accidentally]

Comment: @Tetsujin: I presented MS with my receipt (Serial #) for Office 2011 and they forced me to go to 2016.   2+hours...  You are wise to keep a template image.

Comment: I actually never did it intentionally, it just worked out that way. I do have 5 licenses for Office 365 too, I've just never needed it enough to bother installing it ;-))